# springintegration http inbound gateway: access full Message after conversion

Tags: spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

i'm using spring integration, i've defined an integrationflow that starts with an http request using Http.inboundGateway:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/test")
            .replyChannel("http-response")
            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
            .mappedRequestHeaders(sharedsecretName)
            .requestPayloadType(Map.class)
            )
            .log(this.getClass().getPackageName())
            .channel(MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(SUBSCRIBABLE_CHANNEL).get())
            .get();
```

in subsequent channels the message is sent after the conversion according to

```
.requestPayloadType(Map.class)
```

Is there any way to access the full Message (i need to check the mapped header) instead of the converted one?